# GCE Instance Not Found

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to set up a Kubernetes cluster on GCE using CoreOS as the base OS. But I'm having the following issue when trying to make the cluster a `multizone` cluster by setting the `--cloud-provider` and `--cloud-config` flags.

The below is the output from the API Server on the master node:

```
Jun 15 09:22:09 cos-000-pub-pvt-master.c.project-id.internal kubelet-wrapper[1098]: E0615 09:22:09.790068    1098 gce.go:2380] Failed to retrieve instance: "10.0.0.2"
Jun 15 09:22:09 cos-000-pub-pvt-master.c.project-id.internal kubelet-wrapper[1098]: E0615 09:22:09.790125    1098 gce.go:2414] getInstanceByName/multiple-zones: failed to get instance 10.0.0.2; err: instance not found
Jun 15 09:22:09 cos-000-pub-pvt-master.c.project-id.internal kubelet-wrapper[1098]: E0615 09:22:09.790151    1098 kubelet.go:1131] Unable to construct api.Node object for kubelet: failed to get external ID from cloud provider: instance not found
```

When running `kubectl get nodes` there is no output, but when running `kubectl --namespace kube-system get pods` I see the API Server, Controller Manager, Scheduler and each of the Proxies for each of the nodes. Although I can see them they are restarted every 45-60 seconds.

The GCE config file is as follows:

```
[GLOBAL]
multizone=true
```

If I've left something out that can help let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `--hostname-override` flag was causing this issue. I've removed that and the master is now able to find the node in the GCE API.